# cli assembly error while trying to export datagridview to OpenOffice Calc from c# application in 64bit Windows-7

Tags: c#, datagridview, command-line-interface, .net-assembly, openoffice-calc

I have a `C#` application from which i need to export the `datagridview` to `OpenOffice Calc(version 4.1.1)`. When i build the solution and install it and run it on a 32-bit OS, it works perfectly fine. But it gives me an error when i try to install and run the application in a 64-bit OS. ( I have included an image below of the exception report). After a bit of research I came to know about the Build Properties of the C# solution where I changed the `Active Solution Platform` to `x86` but the problem still exists.

Following are the assemblies involved:
cli_cppuhelper
cli_basetypes
cli_oootypes
cli_uretypes
cli_ure

This is a screenshot of my Solution Build Properties

[image]

This is the error I get when application is made to run on 64-bit OS.
[image]

Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

On 64-bit system, the system can run either 64bit software or 32bit software. What it cannot do is run a mix of it, where some parts are 64bit and some are 32bit. If a part of your program has to be either 32 or 64bit, *all* of your components should be that way. So if you put anything to "AnyCPU", *all* components must be able to run on any CPU, or the startup process will pick the wrong one (Murphys Law).

I see one of your components is x86 (which means 32bit), so put them all into x86 mode.

Comment: There is no such option as x86 for the first component that is in AnyCPU mode.